# Flutter - Horizontal Bar Chart stacked in one bar chart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to achieve this type of horizontal bar chart stacked within one Bar chart. I came across the fl_chart package, but none of it seems to have the type that I'm looking for.  If any champ can support me in giving me steps to how to achieve this or an exemplary code will be so much helpful. Thank you so much in advance.

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Example] |

Comment: Well, you can create your own chart / widget with some custom maths calc.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on which direction I can take for that? I'm quite new to Flutter so I apologize if this is a dumb question

Comment: No, it's not a dumb question xD. But u can do something like have data of your charts and somehow calculate the width of the individual color slots. Let's say your data reaches a max of 100 units so the width of your chart will be `width:100` and u have 10 elements inside your chart data so each color slot should be of `width:10` x10 times (adding 10 units 10 times to make it 100). And give color to each 10 slots. If somehow it makes sense.

Comment: ohh sure, that makes sense. Let me try and see if I can work that out. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: You can get a gist of how to do it https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=3ac45c977574e993e00dabe7efe789a7

Comment: what are you using to represent data like model class?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh do you mean like sqflite or firebase? in my case I'm using sqflite if that answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the code @ChiragBargoojar, I just added bits of customization and the graph works as how I designed it.

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Outcome] |

If anyone else wondering, here's the code:

```
class HorizontalBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  const HorizontalBarChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> chartData = [
      {
        "units": 50,
        "color": cCoffee,
      },
      {
        "units": 10,
        "color": cCyan,
      },
      {
        "units": 70,
        "color": cGreen,
      },
      {
        "units": 100,
        "color": cOrange,
      },
    ];
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 36;
    var totalUnitNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
      totalUnitNum = totalUnitNum + int.parse(chartData[i]["units"].toString());
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++)
              i == chartData.length - 1
                  ? Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                        child: ColoredBox(
                          color: chartData[i]["color"],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width:
                              chartData[i]["units"] / totalUnitNum * maxWidth,
                          height: 16,
                          child: ColoredBox(
                            color: chartData[i]["color"],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 6),
                      ],
                    )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You could also achieve this with a `LinearGradient`.

A LinearGradient takes a `List<Color> colors` and `List<double> stops`.

In order to have clear color boundaries, you duplicate the colors and stops at the boundaries.

Example:

```
colors: [red, red, transparent, transparent, green, green]
stops: [0.0, 0.45, 0.45, 0.55, 0.55, 1]
```

## Full code sample

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chartData = [
      Data(units: 15, color: const Color(0xFF8A5426)),
      Data(units: 20, color: const Color(0xFF00BCD5)),
      Data(units: 12, color: const Color(0xFF7B8700)),
      Data(units: 10, color: const Color(0xFFDD8B11)),
      Data(units: 50, color: const Color(0xFF673BB7)),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child: HorizontalBarChart(
              data: chartData,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Data> data;
  final double gap;

  const HorizontalBarChart({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    this.gap = .02,
  }) : super(key: key);

  List<double> get processedStops {
    double totalGapsWith = gap * (data.length - 1);
    double totalData = data.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b.units);
    return data.fold(<double>[0.0], (List<double> l, d) {
      l.add(l.last + d.units * (1 - totalGapsWith) / totalData);
      l.add(l.last);
      l.add(l.last + gap);
      l.add(l.last);
      return l;
    })
      ..removeLast()
      ..removeLast()
      ..removeLast();
  }

  List<Color> get processedColors {
    return data.fold(
        <Color>[],
        (List<Color> l, d) => [
              ...l,
              d.color,
              d.color,
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.transparent,
            ])
      ..removeLast()
      ..removeLast();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(500),
        ),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          stops: processedStops,
          colors: processedColors,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  final double units;
  final Color color;

  Data({required this.units, required this.color});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> acc = [500, 300, 400, 900, 800];
List<Color> col = [
Colors.red,
Colors.blue,
Colors.orange,
Colors.green,
Colors.pink
];

getSum() {
return acc.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

getAccAver(int index) {
return (acc[index] / getSum() * 100).toInt();
}

Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 20,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++)
            CardAccAve(
              percentage: getAccAver(i),
              leftBorder: i == 0 ? 10 : 0,
              rightBorder: i == acc.length - 1 ? 10 : 0,
              color: col[i],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
),

class CardAccAve extends StatelessWidget {
  CardAccAve({
    Key? key,
    required this.leftBorder,
    required this.rightBorder,
    required this.percentage,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);
  double leftBorder;
  double rightBorder;
  final int percentage;
  Color color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: percentage,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 20,
        child: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1, vertical: 2),
          color: color,
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(leftBorder),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(leftBorder),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(rightBorder),
              topRight: Radius.circular(rightBorder),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image]