# Design this custom slider using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need a custom slider widget which should look like the image attached.

I tried with the flutter slider widget and couldn't find any similar designs.

[image: this is the attached image]

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281800/flutter-horizontal-bar-chart-stacked-in-one-bar-chart I tried this,

Comment: Please post your current code and what is missing/what you are stuck with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this:

```
class Test2 extends StatelessWidget {
 const Test2({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 80,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 40 - withOffset(19),
                  child: const SizedBox(),
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: withOffset(19) - 11,
                  child: const SizedBox(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: const [
                _TestContainer(
                  flex: 15,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 2,
                ),
                _TestContainer(
                  flex: 10,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 2,
                ),
                _TestContainer(
                  flex: 13,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 2,
                ),
                _TestContainer(
                  flex: 10,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

_TestContainer:

```
class _TestContainer extends StatelessWidget {
const _TestContainer({
 Key? key,
 required this.flex,
 required this.color,
}) : super(key: key);
 final int flex;
 final Color color;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Expanded(
  flex: flex,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 5,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

withOffset:

```
int withOffset(double bmi) {
 final off = bmi;
 return off.toInt();
}
```